# Endless Scrolling Background in SpriteKit

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, sprite-kit

I am attempting to make a side scrolling game using Apple's SpriteKit. When wanting to make a endless scrolling background I came across this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19349168/sprite-kit-side-scrolling).

After implementing the solution it does appear to work **although** it drops my FPS significantly. This is probably due to the fact that the images positions are being recalculated on every frame.

I feel like it would be much better if I could use one or more `SKAction` calls to take care of this animation for me but I'm not certain how to implement it.

Thoughts?

The code I have so far in my scene class (this only animates the background across the screen once though)

```
- (void)addBackgroundTileAtPoint:(CGPoint)point {

    SKSpriteNode *bg = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"background"];
    bg.anchorPoint = CGPointZero;
    bg.position = point;
    bg.name = @"background";
    bg.zPosition = -99;
    [self addChild:bg];

    SKAction *sequence = [SKAction sequence:@[
        [SKAction moveByX:-(bg.size.width * 2) y:0 duration:10],
        [SKAction removeFromParent]
    ]];
    [bg runAction: sequence];
}
```

Comment: Actions won't do you any good unless the scrolling is constant: same direction at same speed. Even then I doubt actions will be noticably faster than the answer implementation. Though it may be faster if instead of enumerateByName you'd just have references to the two background sprites so that SK doesn't need to search the node graph by name.

Comment: You need a recursive call here inside *sequence. i.e after [SKAction removeFromParent], add [self addBackgroundTileAtPoint:];, or you should use repeat action without removing the background from super view

Comment: @LearnCocos2D if actions aren't the way to go did you have any suggestions on optimizing the other answers solution or did you have a different solution. When running that answer's solution on the emulator the FPS immediately drops from 60 to ~30.

Comment: I am pretty sure the simulator caps the application frame rate at around 30fps, so the slow down your seeing is just a side effect of that and not a sign that the app is struggling.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I did a small component called `SKScrollingNode` for that particular need in my last open source project : [SprityBird](https://github.com/kirualex/SprityBird).

FPS was not an issue even with 3 or 4 layers (for parallax), but you may need to try it yourself.

To use it you just have to add it like any other node and giving it a `scrollingSpeed` likeso :

```
back = [SKScrollingNode scrollingNodeWithImageNamed:@"back" inContainerWidth:WIDTH(self)];
[back setScrollingSpeed:BACK_SCROLLING_SPEED];
[self addChild:back];
```

SKScrollingNode.h

```
@interface SKScrollingNode : SKSpriteNode

@property (nonatomic) CGFloat scrollingSpeed;

+ (id) scrollingNodeWithImageNamed:(NSString *)name inContainerWidth:(float) width;
- (void) update:(NSTimeInterval)currentTime;

@end
```

SKScrollingNode.m

```
@implementation SKScrollingNode

+ (id) scrollingNodeWithImageNamed:(NSString *)name inContainerWidth:(float) width
{
    UIImage * image = [UIImage imageNamed:name];

    SKScrollingNode * realNode = [SKScrollingNode spriteNodeWithColor:[UIColor clearColor] size:CGSizeMake(width, image.size.height)];
    realNode.scrollingSpeed = 1;

    float total = 0;
    while(total<(width + image.size.width)){
        SKSpriteNode * child = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:name ];
        [child setAnchorPoint:CGPointZero];
        [child setPosition:CGPointMake(total, 0)];
        [realNode addChild:child];
        total+=child.size.width;
    }

    return realNode;
}

- (void) update:(NSTimeInterval)currentTime
{
    [self.children enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(SKSpriteNode * child, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        child.position = CGPointMake(child.position.x-self.scrollingSpeed, child.position.y);
        if (child.position.x <= -child.size.width){
            float delta = child.position.x+child.size.width;
            child.position = CGPointMake(child.size.width*(self.children.count-1)+delta, child.position.y);
        }
    }];
}   
@end
```

Comment: Awesome work but with the release of iOS 9 enumerateObjectsUsingBlock throws an incompatible-block-pointer error when using and SKSpriteNode. After having a play and then search some more I found the following post that solves the issue. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33584180/incompatible-block-pointer-skspritenode/33584230#33584230

Answer (score 1):

I've been working on a library for an infinite tile scroller, you can easily use it to create a scrolling background. Take a look at it:

[RPTileScroller](https://github.com/raspu/RPTileScroller)

I made an effort to make it the most efficient possible, but I am not a game developer. I tried it with my iPhone 5 with random colors tiles of 10x10 pixels, and is running on a solid 60 fps.