# XCODE/SK SpriteKit/ How to have my sprite move

Tags: ios, css, xcode

I desperately need your help. So I am new to SpriteKit for XCODE and I am just getting use to the mechanics. I currently have a background image and a sprite positioned at the center.

**The Problem**

The sprite moves horizontal across the screen which is what I want. However, the sprite moves off the screen and what I want is a **continuous motion between the sprite and the background.** For instance, this game in the video link below shows the kind of relationship I want. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9RYgMqkRgoE

```
       SKSpriteNode *mega =[ SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"Mega.png"];
        mega.position = CGPointMake (self. frame.size.width/2, self.frame.size.height/2);
        mega.size = CGSizeMake(30,30);
        mega.zPosition = 3;

        mega.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:mega.frame.size];

        mega.physicsBody.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = YES;
        mega.physicsBody.mass = 0.2;
        mega.physicsBody.affectedByGravity = NO;
        mega.physicsBody.dynamic = NO;

    SKAction *moveNodeUp = [SKAction moveByX:500 y:0.0 duration:10];
    [mega runAction: moveNodeUp];



    [self addChild:mega];

            SKAction *repeater = [SKAction repeatActionForever:moveNodeUp];

    [mega runAction:repeater];

    SKSpriteNode *bg = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"bg.png"];
    bg.position = CGPointMake(160, 284);
    bg.size = CGSizeMake(self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height);

    SKAction *moveNodeForward = [SKAction moveByX:500 y:0.0 duration:10];
    bg runAction: moveNodeForward];



    [self addChild:bg];
```

Comment: Mega.png is the sprite and bg is the background

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Move the background, not the sprite.**

If you take a close look at that video you will notice that the character never moves too far from the center of the screen. The motion of the background (along with the animations on the character) creates an illusion of motion.

If you remove these lines:

```
SKAction *moveNodeUp = [SKAction moveByX:500 y:0.0 duration:10];
[mega runAction: moveNodeUp];
```

The player will appear to be moving to the left when you move the background.

I would recommend taking a look at questions such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21703194/endless-scrolling-background-in-spritekit?rq=1) if you want to create a game similar to the one in the video

Comment: How do I move the background without having it leave the screen? Thanks

Comment: The background image has to be bigger--or wider--than the size of the screen.