# How to make a UIImageView repeat forever across the screen [x-axis]

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

I am developing a game on xCode, but I ran into a problem.
I was able to make the `UIImageView` move <------- left across the iPhone screen, but it I want it to repeat as soon as it begins to move so it could look endless.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dxbnH.png]

Lets say that one piece of the floor in that app is a `UIImageView`, how can I make that `UIImageView` repeat across the screen [x-axis] as shown in that app. [NOT MY APP]

```
-(void)whiteFloor{
    whiteFloor.center = CGPointMake(whiteFloor.center.x-1);   
    if(whiteFloor.center.x < 130){
        [self placeGround];
    }
}

-(void)placeGround {
    // Also would I need to make a int?
    //what would write here
}
```

Comment: I would take a look at: `resizableImageWithCapInsets` https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIImage/resizableImageWithCapInsets:

Comment: If you want it animated, I would also make the UIImageView a little bigger, and animate it left until you get to the end. When you do, snap the image back to x=0.

Comment: Interestingly I just found somebody implementing this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22073053/2982796 - It should be able to be adjusted if you do not wish to use `SpriteKit`

Comment: I don't want to use Spritekit sorry :/

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure there are better ways to do it if you use SpriteKit, but if you don't want to use it, you can maybe use 2 UIImageView one after another to create the endless effect.