# Incompatible block pointer SKSpriteNode

Tags: ios, objective-c, skspritenode

This is my code

```
- (void) update:(NSTimeInterval)currentTime
{
    [self.children enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(SKSpriteNode * child, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    child.position = CGPointMake(child.position.x-self.scrollingSpeed, child.position.y);
    if (child.position.x <= -child.size.width){
        float delta = child.position.x+child.size.width;
        child.position = CGPointMake(child.size.width*(self.children.count-1)+delta, child.position.y);
        }
    }];
}
```

And i am getting an an error

```
Incompatible block pointer types sending 'void (^)(SKSpriteNode *__strong, NSUInteger, BOOL *)' to parameter of type 'void (^ _Nonnull)(SKNode * _Nonnull __strong, NSUInteger, BOOL * _Nonnull)'
```

and I don't know why. I tried changing it to `SKNode` but it says size does not exist.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need to update your question with the complete and exact error message. Never abbreviate error messages when you post them.

Comment: @rmaddy sorry i will add that right now!

Comment: Based on the error, simply change `SKSpriteNode` to `SKNode`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The enumeration block syntax is not correct, you need to change:

```
 [self.children enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(SKSpriteNode * child, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop)
{
    child.position = CGPointMake(child.position.x-self.scrollingSpeed, child.position.y);
    if (child.position.x <= -child.size.width)
    {
       float delta = child.position.x+child.size.width;
       child.position = CGPointMake(child.size.width*(self.children.count-1)+delta, child.position.y);
    }
}];
```

to

```
 [self.children enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id object, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop)
 {
    SKSpriteNode *child = (SKSpriteNode *)object;
    child.position = CGPointMake(child.position.x-self.scrollingSpeed, child.position.y);
    if (child.position.x <= -child.size.width)
    {
       float delta = child.position.x+child.size.width;
       child.position = CGPointMake(child.size.width*(self.children.count-1)+delta, child.position.y);
    }
}];
```

The enumeration block's first parameter is of type `id` not `SKSpriteNode`. There is no such implementation for [NSArray](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:).

Comment: Thank you it works perfect now! appreciate it a lot. I started developing more with swift but i figured id give OBJ-C a try!

Comment: @JamesAnderson: Happy coding with Obj C.