# Gravity not affecting a node when endless background is enabled in sprite kit

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit

When I implement the following code, my main character is not affected by gravity.

```
SKSpriteNode *ball = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"ball.png"];
ball.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithCircleOfRadius:ball.size.height/2];
ball.physicsBody.dynamic = YES;
ball.physicsBody.linearDamping = NO;
ball.physicsBody.angularDamping = NO;
ball.physicsBody.friction = 0;
ball.physicsBody.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = YES;
ball.position = CGPointZero;
ball.zPosition = 1;
[myWorld addChild:ball];
```

Here's the background

```
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    SKSpriteNode * bg = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"background"];
    //bg.anchorPoint = CGPointZero;
    bg.position = CGPointMake(i * bg.size.width, 0);
    bg.name = @"background.png";
    //bg.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithEdgeFromPoint:CGPointMake(-bg.frame.size.width/2, -bg.frame.size.height/2 +20) toPoint:CGPointMake(bg.frame.size.width/2, -bg.frame.size.height/2 + 20)];
    bg.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithEdgeLoopFromRect:bg.frame];
    [self addChild:bg];
}
```

I tried the code here [Stack discussion here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19349168/sprite-kit-side-scrolling) and everything works as expected, except the gravity on the y axis.

Gravity in the scene:

```
if (self = [super initWithSize:size]) {
    self.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5);
    self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake(0, -2);
    [self startGravityIncrease];

........

- (void)startGravityIncrease {
    SKAction *blockAction = [SKAction runBlock:^{
        CGVector gravity = self.physicsWorld.gravity;
        gravity.dx += 0.6;
        gravity.dy -= 0.3;
        self.physicsWorld.gravity = gravity;
    }];
    SKAction *waitAction = [SKAction waitForDuration:5];
    SKAction *sequenceAction = [SKAction sequence:@[waitAction, blockAction]];
    SKAction *repeatAction = [SKAction repeatActionForever:sequenceAction];

    [self runAction:repeatAction];
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: How is your main character declared?

Comment: SKSpriteNode *ball = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"ball.png"];
        ball.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithCircleOfRadius:ball.size.height/2];
        ball.physicsBody.dynamic = YES;
        ball.physicsBody.linearDamping = NO;
        ball.physicsBody.angularDamping = NO;
        ball.physicsBody.friction = 0;
        ball.physicsBody.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = YES;
        ball.position = CGPointZero;
        ball.zPosition = 1;
        [myWorld addChild:ball];

Comment: Please edit your answer with the code instead of putting it in a comment.

Comment: You are setting up a block which increases the gravity along the x axis and decreases the gravity along the y axis every 5 seconds. We cannot tell you what's wrong till you explain how you intended for the gravity to work.

Comment: @ZeMoon the gravity along the y axis is also increasing to higher vector in the negative direction. I want the gravity to change over time so that the game difficulty keeps on increasing and the trajectory varies as well since the increments along the two axis will be different.

Comment: @NitinRimmalapudi please describe in your question how the gravity is not working with your code, in terms of expectation vs reality. The current code increases gravity in the south-east direction of the screen, as far as I can see.

Comment: @ZeMoon intended the gravity to work in the South East direction. But the ball stays stationary in the centre of the screen. But if I comment out the for loop shown above the gravity seems to act on the ball as intended

Comment: enable showsPhysics to check if it isn't stopped by collisions